# No link to the 10k moderation tools when my account has a review suspension

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, review-suspension

I'm missing a convenient way to access the [10k moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools) as described on SO privilege help, because it shows I'm suspended from review. I can still access them by directly navigating to `/tools` or via the help center, however.

Is this a bug? Or is it intentionally inconvenient? Or should I have been prevented from accessing moderator tools as well with the review suspension?

[image: Screenshot of the dropdown of reviews with suspension message and no link to tools]

As you see above, the "tools" link is missing. Can we please get it back?

Comment: Moderator tool access shouldn't be related to bans from the queues, AFAIK.

Comment: What way are you using to access the mod tools? Is the "tools" link in the top-right of the review queue dropdown missing when you're review banned? Or are you used to navigating to the full /reviews page and clicking the "Tools" button in the top-right?

Comment: @Spevacus, the former one. The message about review suspension is the only dropdown content. I don't see */reviews* page, assuming you meant */review* page, the tools are accessible from there.

Comment: Gotcha. That sounds annoying. Maybe you want to tag this with [tag:feature-request] and include a screenshot that shows that the "tools" link isn't available in that dropdown due to being review-suspended, and ask for this functionality to be changed? I'd certainly support that change. The mod tools don't really have much actionable content, it's pretty much just informational. There's no reason for them to be more difficult to get to due to a review suspension, IMO.

Comment: Moderator tools are something that only moderators can use. 10k users tools page title is "Moderation Tools". Also, as mentioned in above comment, this better be feature request, I've edited everything in.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron Is this a feature request or a support request? It certainly doesn't seem like expected behavior to me? It's unclear whether it's a bug or by design, so it's not really a request for new functionality.

Comment: @ColleenV feature request, and it's even under review now.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron So we know this is an intentional design and not an oversight? It seems weird that we have to ask SE to not remove a link we still have access to just because we're review banned and call it a "feature" instead of a "bug fix".

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron I agree with ColleenV, and have retagged it as a bug, because it's inconsistent: either the link should be there, or if review suspensions are supposed to also ban the user from accessing moderation tools, accessing them directly should also be prevented.

Comment: @Sonic well, still think they removed the link on purpose, but as I can't know, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron I think if the intention was to block access to the 10K tools when someone is review-banned, Alex wouldn't be able to to access the tools by typing the url in. Most likely this is just a bug that was missed because it's rare that 10k users get banned from reviews and those that have in the past didn't try to access the 10k tools from that link during their ban.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link to `Tools` in the Reviews topbar dropdown will now show for users who have enough rep to see it, regardless of review suspension status.

> did something not good
> on review queues…it's ok
> you can still see tools